# Errors with DateDiff between two calculated columns in PowerBi

Tags: dax, powerbi-desktop

I work for an FI and need tips on creating a measure that will allow me to find the days between when a transaction takes an account negative and when the next deposit takes the account positive. Right now we have identified the negative and positive dates using 2 calculated columns. But the measure used to find the difference between those days is not working.

Negative balance calculated column:

```
Balance After Tran Neg =

IF('Accounts Going Negative'[CATEGORY] = 

        "W" && 'Accounts Going Negative'[PRINCIPAL] < 'Accounts Going Negative'[NEW_BALANCE] 
         && 'Accounts Going Negative'[NEW_BALANCE] < 0, 
        'Accounts Going Negative'[POSTING_DATE], BLANK())
```

Positive balance calculated column:

```
Balance After Tran Pos =

IF('Accounts Going Negative'[CATEGORY]= 

        "D" && 'Accounts Going Negative'[PRINCIPAL] 
        > 'Accounts Going Negative'[NEW_BALANCE] 
        && 'Accounts Going Negative'[NEW_BALANCE] > 0, 
        'Accounts Going Negative'[POSTING_DATE], BLANK())
```

I created a measure that should calculate the days between the two dates:

```
Date Diff =

DATEDIFF('Accounts Going Negative'[Balance After Tran Neg],

       'Accounts Going Negative'[Balance After Tran Pos], DAY)
```

This datediff measure just returns with blank results in the visual. Any tips as to how to solve this problem?

Thank you!